# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor to a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Custom Layer :

```
class XLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self):
    super(XLayer, self).__init__()
    print('X Layer is Created')

  def call(self, x):
    some_procesing_on_x()
    return x
```

Custom Model :

```
class XModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(XModel, self).__init__()

    self.conv1_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 5, strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',padding='SAME')
    self.conv1_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 5, strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',padding='SAME')
    self.relu1 = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
    self.x1 = XLayer()

    self.output1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')

  def call(self, input):
    
    x = self.conv1_1(input)
    x = self.conv1_2(x)
    x = self.relu1(x)
    x = self.x1(x)


    x = self.output1(x)

    return x
```

Problem is with xlayer which uses some function that convert tensorflow data to numpy array resulting: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (x_model/x_layer/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported error while saving my model.

So i need some way to save my model. Some old solution in stackoverflow suggest downgrading numpy but that results in slow code and also do not solve the problem.

Comment: The traceback is incomplete, you need to include the whole traceback

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i've added a ss of an error if it can help.

Comment: And... do you realize you have an `assert(batch_size == 1)` (which is strange) while you're getting exactly an `AssertionError` in the stack trace? Why don't you put the entire stack trace?

Comment: It is literally triggering the assertion error that you put inside call, not sure how we can help other than pointing out the error.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy sorry for incomplete info. I think while saving whole model tensorflow needs all variable and operation in tf but my layer uses some fuction that uses numpy array to convert tensorflow to numpy array which result in following error:
Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (x_model/x_layer/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

Comment: That seems to be a completely different problem, you just edited the question to be a different issue that still we cannot answer because of missing information (what numpy function are you talking about?, what does some_procesing_on_x look like?)